# TransformedTargetRegressor does not inherit feature_importances_ attribute

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, transform, linear-regression

I am using [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) to transform my target into log space. It is done like

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
clf = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=GradientBoostingRegressor(**params),
       func=np.log1p, inverse_func=np.expm1)
```

However when I later call

```
feature_importance = clf.feature_importances_
```

I get

> AttributeError: 'TransformedTargetRegressor' object has no attribute
>   'feature_importances_'

I would have thought that all the attributes of the original class would be inherited. How can this be solved?

For further context [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html) is an official example. Replacing the initialization line with mine would result in the crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [TransformedTargetRegressor Doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) says, one can access its component regressor through `.regressor_`.
So this is what you want:

```
clf.regressor_.feature_importances_
```

Workable code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor #only in sklearn==0.20.2

# #############################################################################
# Load data
boston = datasets.load_boston()
X, y = shuffle(boston.data, boston.target, random_state=13)
X = X.astype(np.float32)
offset = int(X.shape[0] * 0.9)
X_train, y_train = X[:offset], y[:offset]
X_test, y_test = X[offset:], y[offset:]

# #############################################################################
# Fit regression model
params = {'n_estimators': 500, 'max_depth': 4, 'min_samples_split': 2,
          'learning_rate': 0.01, 'loss': 'ls'}
#clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params)
clf = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=GradientBoostingRegressor(**params),
       func=np.log1p, inverse_func=np.expm1)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, clf.predict(X_test))
print("MSE: %.4f" % mse)

print(clf.regressor_.feature_importances_)
```

Its output:

```
MSE: 7.7145
[6.45223704e-02 1.32970011e-04 2.92221184e-03 4.48101769e-04
 3.57392613e-02 2.02435922e-01 1.22755948e-02 7.03996426e-02
 1.54903176e-03 1.90771421e-02 1.98577625e-02 1.63376111e-02
 5.54302378e-01]
```